# Prevent identity alerts from being fired

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Im working on a project where i have decided to implement email's as usernames and completely drop the default MVC username field. I have set up identity registration like this:

Model:

```
[Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Controller setup:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            { ...
```

However, due to this change, whenever i have a situation where a user enters an email that already exists, the identity fires that the username and email already both exist.

[image]

How do i prevent the "Name is already taken" alert from being fired in this situation? I have attempted to remove the username paramater from the "new ApplicationUser" call, but then it throws me an alert that it cant be null either. Thanks!

Comment: @AntarrByrd, posted the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `AddErrors(result);` is causing the probleme.
You can change the method to ignore the errors that start with "Name"

```
private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result, string[] ignoreStartWith)
{
     foreach (var error in result.Errors)
     {
          if (!ignoreStartWith.Any(s => error.StartsWith(s)))
          {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
          }
     }
}
```

And use it like

```
AddErrors(result, ignoreStartWith:new[] { "Name" });
```